# ADD/DELETE Row in P-Table updates JSON

Tags: json, angular, typescript, crud, primeng

My table has to be CRUD (Create, Read, Update and Delete). All those actions have to be updated in my JSON-file. Read and Update works but I can't seem to figure out how to Delete a specific row in the table. Can't use Jquery or AngularJS only Angular 6. Can anyone help me out?

I have to do this for 4 more Arrays like this. So If someone can explain me how it works with 1. I think I can handle them all. My question is mostly about delete or splice but if you also know the answer for adding a new empty line/object which I can change in my p-table using Editable columns it would be even better.

**JSON:**

```
Partijen = [
  {
    "Adressen": [{
        "iAdresID" : "118",
        "iID" : "74",
        "sType" : "Partij",
        "sSoort" : "BezoekAdres",
        "iWijkCode" : "3356",
        "sSraatCode" : "ME",
        "iHuisNr" : "4",
        "sToev" : "",
        "sStraat" : "Boerenschouw",
        "sPlaats" : "PAPENDRECHT",
        "sGemeente" : "PAPENDRECHT",
        "rLatitudeX" : "51,83249",
        "rlongitudeY" : "4,71396",
        "sAdres" : "Boerenschouw 4, 3356ME PAPENDRECHT"
    },
    {
        "iAdresID" : "119",
        "iID" : "74",
        "sType" : "Partij",
        "sSoort" : "PostAdres",
        "iWijkCode" : "3356",
        "sSraatCode" : "ME",
        "iHuisNr" : "4",
        "sToev" : "",
        "sStraat" : "Boerenschouw",
        "sPlaats" : "PAPENDRECHT",
        "sGemeente" : "PAPENDRECHT",
        "rLatitudeX" : "51,83249",
        "rlongitudeY" : "4,713613",
        "sAdres" : "Boerenschouw 4, 3356ME PAPENDRECHT"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

**Part of P-table**

```
<p-tabPanel header="Adressen" leftIcon="pi pi-home">
            <p-table [value]="Partijen" [(selection)]="Adressen">
                <ng-template pTemplate="header">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Soort</th>
                        <th>Straatnaam</th>
                        <th>Huisnummer</th>
                        <th>Wijkcode</th>
                        <th>Straatcode</th>
                        <th>Plaats</th>
                        <th>Verwijderen</th>
                    </tr>
                </ng-template>
                <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-Partij>
                    <tr>
                    <td pEditableColumn>
                        <p-cellEditor>
                            <ng-template pTemplate="input">
                                <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="Partij.Adressen[0].sSoort">
                            </ng-template>
                            <ng-template pTemplate="output">
                                {{Partij.Adressen[0].sSoort}}
                            </ng-template>
                        </p-cellEditor>
                    </td>
                    <td pEditableColumn>
                            <p-cellEditor>
                                <ng-template pTemplate="input">
                                    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="Partij.Adressen[0].sStraat">
                                </ng-template>
                                <ng-template pTemplate="output">
                                    {{Partij.Adressen[0].sStraat}}
                                </ng-template>
                            </p-cellEditor>
                        </td>
                        <td pEditableColumn>
                            <p-cellEditor>
                                <ng-template pTemplate="input">
                                    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="Partij.Adressen[0].iHuisNr">
                                </ng-template>
                                <ng-template pTemplate="output">
                                    {{Partij.Adressen[0].iHuisNr}}
                                </ng-template>
                            </p-cellEditor>
                        </td>
                        <td pEditableColumn>
                            <p-cellEditor>
                                <ng-template pTemplate="input">
                                    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="Partij.Adressen[0].iWijkCode">
                                </ng-template>
                                <ng-template pTemplate="output">
                                    {{Partij.Adressen[0].iWijkCode}}
                                </ng-template>
                            </p-cellEditor>
                        </td>
                        <td pEditableColumn>
                            <p-cellEditor>
                                <ng-template pTemplate="input">
                                    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="Partij.Adressen[0].sSraatCode">
                                </ng-template>
                                <ng-template pTemplate="output">
                                    {{Partij.Adressen[0].sSraatCode}}
                                </ng-template>
                            </p-cellEditor>
                        </td>
                        <td pEditableColumn>
                            <p-cellEditor>
                                <ng-template pTemplate="input">
                                    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="Partij.Adressen[0].sPlaats">
                                </ng-template>
                                <ng-template pTemplate="output">
                                    {{Partij.Adressen[0].sPlaats}}
                                </ng-template>
                            </p-cellEditor>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <button pButton type="button" label="Verwijder" class="buttonCSS" (click)="on_Verwijderen()"></button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </ng-template>
            </p-table>
        </p-tabPanel>
</p-tabView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the row data to the delete method

```
<p-column> 
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-row="rowData">
         <button pButton type="button" label="Verwijder" class="buttonCSS" (click)="on_Verwijderen(row)"></button>
    </ng-template>
</p-column>
```

then delete that row from the array the the table is using for a value based on a unique id

```
on_Verwijderen(row: any){
            this.Partijen.Adressen.splice(this.Partijen.Adressen.findIndex((r) => (r.iAdresID === row.iAdresID)), 1);
    }
```

That is how I have done it when using p-column, it looks like you already have a variable Partij with the row data, so maybe you can just have

```
<button pButton type="button" label="Verwijder" class="buttonCSS" (click)="on_Verwijderen(Partij)"></button>
```

although I am a bit confused by your table setup, you seem to be explicitly accessing the Adressen array by index, which doesn't seem right.